unable to use elastic search using java
I am trying to connect my java application to Amazon Elastic Search Instance and work on product search but I have been failing for a few days finally asking you guys if you can help.
My Elastic Search Instance
{
  "name" : "85f0ea170418836832b23ba9381b02e1",
  "cluster_name" : "034362065489:atosell",
  "cluster_uuid" : "QvnKushRQxKnOqqXwzqq3Q",
  "version" : {
    "distribution" : "opensearch",
    "number" : "2.15.0",
    "build_type" : "tar",
    "build_hash" : "unknown",
    "build_date" : "2024-09-13T11:21:22.242025742Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "9.10.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "7.10.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "7.0.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "The OpenSearch Project: https://opensearch.org/"
}

Elastic Search Configuration
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.ClientConfiguration;
    import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.elc.ElasticsearchConfiguration;

    @Configuration
    public class ElasticSearchConfig extends ElasticsearchConfiguration {

        @Override
        public ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration() {
            return ClientConfiguration.builder()
                    .connectedTo("search-atosell-ezrvtmvhttw6fjztfsgkbndgbu.eu-central-1.es.amazonaws.com:443")
                    .usingSsl()
                    .withBasicAuth("username", "password")
                    .build();
        }
    }

My POM File:
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2</version>
            <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
        </parent>
        <groupId>com.app</groupId>
        <artifactId>fluxix</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <packaging>jar</packaging>
        <name>fluxix</name>
        <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
        <url/>
        <licenses>
            <license/>
        </licenses>
        <developers>
            <developer/>
        </developers>
        <scm>
            <connection/>
            <developerConnection/>
            <tag/>
            <url/>
        </scm>
        <properties>
            <java.version>21</java.version>
        </properties>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
                <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
                <version>2.6.0</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
                <artifactId>dynamodb</artifactId>
                <version>2.27.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
                <artifactId>dynamodb-enhanced</artifactId>
                <version>2.27.2</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
                <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
                <version>0.12.6</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
                <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
                <version>0.12.6</version>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
                <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
                <version>0.12.6</version>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.stripe</groupId>
                <artifactId>stripe-java</artifactId>
                <version>26.10.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
                <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
                <version>8.15.2</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                <optional>true</optional>
            </dependency>
            <!-- <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency> -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>

        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>
                                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            </exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>

    </project>

Elastic Search Product Controller
    package com.app.fluxix.elasticsearch.controller;

    import com.app.fluxix.elasticsearch.entity.ElasticSearchProduct;
    import com.app.fluxix.elasticsearch.service.ElasticSearchProductService;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

    import java.util.List;

    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/api/elasticsearch/product")
    public class ElasticSearchProductController {

        @Autowired
        private ElasticSearchProductService elasticSearchProductService;

        @PostMapping("/add")
        public ResponseEntity<ElasticSearchProduct> addProduct(@RequestBody ElasticSearchProduct elasticSearchProduct) {
            return ResponseEntity.ok(elasticSearchProductService.addProduct(elasticSearchProduct));
        }

        @PostMapping("/addMultiple")
        public ResponseEntity<List<ElasticSearchProduct>> addProducts(@RequestBody List<ElasticSearchProduct> elasticSearchProducts) {
            return ResponseEntity.ok(elasticSearchProductService.addProducts(elasticSearchProducts));
        }

        @GetMapping("/get/{id}")
        public ResponseEntity<ElasticSearchProduct> getProduct(@PathVariable String id) {
            ElasticSearchProduct elasticSearchProduct = elasticSearchProductService.getProduct(id);
            if (elasticSearchProduct != null) {
                return ResponseEntity.ok(elasticSearchProduct);
            }
            return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
        }

        @GetMapping("/getAll")
        public ResponseEntity<Iterable<ElasticSearchProduct>> getAllProducts() {
            return ResponseEntity.ok(elasticSearchProductService.getAllProducts());
        }

        @PostMapping("/update/{id}")
        public ResponseEntity<ElasticSearchProduct> updateProduct(
                @RequestBody ElasticSearchProduct elasticSearchProduct,
                @PathVariable String id
        ) {
            ElasticSearchProduct updatedElasticSearchProduct =
                    elasticSearchProductService.updateProduct(elasticSearchProduct, id);
            if (updatedElasticSearchProduct != null) {
                return ResponseEntity.ok(updatedElasticSearchProduct);
            }
            return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
        }

        @DeleteMapping("/delete/{id}")
        public ResponseEntity<Void> deleteProduct(@PathVariable String id) {
            elasticSearchProductService.deleteProduct(id);
            return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
        }

        @DeleteMapping("/deleteMultiple")
        public ResponseEntity<Void> deleteProducts(@RequestBody List<String> ids) {
            elasticSearchProductService.deleteProducts(ids);
            return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
        }

        @DeleteMapping("/deleteAll")
        public ResponseEntity<Void> deleteAllProducts() {
            elasticSearchProductService.deleteAllProducts();
            return ResponseEntity.noContent().build(); // Respond with HTTP 204 No Content
        }

        @GetMapping("/search/byName")
        public ResponseEntity<List<ElasticSearchProduct>> searchByName(@RequestParam String name) {
            List<ElasticSearchProduct> elasticSearchProducts = elasticSearchProductService.searchByName(name);
            return ResponseEntity.ok(elasticSearchProducts);
        }

        @GetMapping("/search/byPrice")
        public ResponseEntity<List<ElasticSearchProduct>> searchByPrice(@RequestParam Double price) {
            List<ElasticSearchProduct> elasticSearchProducts = elasticSearchProductService.searchByPrice(price);
            return ResponseEntity.ok(elasticSearchProducts);
        }

        @GetMapping("/search/byField")
        public ResponseEntity<List<ElasticSearchProduct>> searchByField(
                @RequestParam String fieldName,
                @RequestParam String fieldValue) {

            List<ElasticSearchProduct> elasticSearchProducts = elasticSearchProductService.searchByField(fieldName, fieldValue);
            return ResponseEntity.ok(elasticSearchProducts);
        }

        @GetMapping("/search")
        public ResponseEntity<List<ElasticSearchProduct>> search(@RequestParam String text) {
            List<ElasticSearchProduct> elasticSearchProducts = elasticSearchProductService.searchByText(text);
            return ResponseEntity.ok(elasticSearchProducts);
        }
    }

Elastic Search Product Service
    package com.app.fluxix.elasticsearch.service;

    import com.app.fluxix.elasticsearch.entity.ElasticSearchProduct;
    import com.app.fluxix.elasticsearch.repo.ElasticSearchProductRepo;
    import org.slf4j.Logger;
    import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchOperations;
    import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.SearchHit;
    import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.query.Criteria;
    import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.query.CriteriaQuery;
    import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.query.Query;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

    import java.util.Optional;

    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.stream.Collectors;

    @Service
    public class ElasticSearchProductService {
        private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ElasticSearchProductService.class);

        @Autowired
        private ElasticSearchProductRepo elasticSearchProductRepo;

        @Autowired
        private ElasticsearchOperations elasticsearchOperations;

        public ElasticSearchProduct addProduct(ElasticSearchProduct elasticSearchProduct) {
            logger.info("Inserting new elasticSearchProduct: {}", elasticSearchProduct.getTitle());
            return elasticSearchProductRepo.save(elasticSearchProduct);
        }

        public List<ElasticSearchProduct> addProducts(List<ElasticSearchProduct> elasticSearchProducts) {
            logger.info("Inserting multiple elasticSearchProducts");
            return (List<ElasticSearchProduct>) elasticSearchProductRepo.saveAll(elasticSearchProducts);
        }

        public ElasticSearchProduct getProduct(String id) {
            logger.info("Fetching product with ID: {}", id);
            Optional<ElasticSearchProduct> productOpt = elasticSearchProductRepo.findById(id);
            return productOpt.orElse(null);
        }

        public Iterable<ElasticSearchProduct> getAllProducts() {
            logger.info("Fetching all products");
            return elasticSearchProductRepo.findAll();
        }

        public ElasticSearchProduct updateProduct(ElasticSearchProduct elasticSearchProduct, String id) {
            logger.info("Updating elasticSearchProduct with ID: {}", id);
            Optional<ElasticSearchProduct> existingProductOpt = elasticSearchProductRepo.findById(id);

            if (existingProductOpt.isPresent()) {
                ElasticSearchProduct existingElasticSearchProduct = existingProductOpt.get();
                existingElasticSearchProduct.setTitle(elasticSearchProduct.getTitle());
                existingElasticSearchProduct.setDescription(elasticSearchProduct.getDescription());
                return elasticSearchProductRepo.save(existingElasticSearchProduct);
            }

            logger.error("ElasticSearchProduct with ID: {} not found", id);
            return null;
        }

        public void deleteProduct(String id) {
            logger.info("Deleting product with ID: {}", id);

            if (elasticSearchProductRepo.existsById(id)) {
                elasticSearchProductRepo.deleteById(id);
                logger.info("ElasticSearchProduct with ID: {} deleted", id);
            } else {
                logger.error("ElasticSearchProduct with ID: {} not found", id);
            }
        }

        public void deleteProducts(List<String> ids) {
            logger.info("Deleting multiple products with IDs: {}", ids);

            Iterable<ElasticSearchProduct> productsToDelete = elasticSearchProductRepo.findAllById(ids);
            elasticSearchProductRepo.deleteAll(productsToDelete);

            logger.info("Products with IDs: {} deleted", ids);
        }

        public void deleteAllProducts() {
            logger.info("Deleting all products");
            elasticSearchProductRepo.deleteAll();
            logger.info("All products have been deleted");
        }

        public List<ElasticSearchProduct> searchByName(String name) {
            return elasticSearchProductRepo.findByName(name);
        }

        public List<ElasticSearchProduct> searchByPrice(Double price) {
            return elasticSearchProductRepo.findByPrice(price);
        }

        public List<ElasticSearchProduct> searchByField(String fieldName, String fieldValue) {
            logger.info("Searching products by field: {} with value: {}", fieldName, fieldValue);

            Criteria criteria = Criteria.where(fieldName).is(fieldValue);
            Query query = new CriteriaQuery(criteria);

            return elasticsearchOperations.search(query, ElasticSearchProduct.class).getSearchHits()
                    .stream()
                    .map(SearchHit::getContent)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
        }

        public List<ElasticSearchProduct> searchByText(String text) {
            logger.info("Searching products by text: {}", text);
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria("name").matches(text)
                    .or(new Criteria("category").matches(text))
                    .or(new Criteria("description").matches(text));

            Query query = new CriteriaQuery(criteria);
            return elasticsearchOperations.search(query, ElasticSearchProduct.class).getSearchHits()
                    .stream()
                    .map(SearchHit::getContent)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
        }
    }

The below error seems concerning, however fullstacktrace is also pasted below:
        org.elasticsearch.client.ResponseException: method [PUT], host [https://search-atosell-ezrvtmvhttw6fjztfsgkbndgbu.eu-central-1.es.amazonaws.com:443], URI [/products], status line [HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable] {"error":"Content-Type header [application/vnd.elasticsearch+json; compatible-with=8] is not supported","status":406}

Error stack trace:
    "

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/

 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.3.2)

org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.ElasticsearchRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(ElasticsearchRepositoryFactoryBean.java:69) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1853) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1802) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    ... 58 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: method [PUT], host [https://search-atosell-ezrvtmvhttw6fjztfsgkbndgbu.eu-central-1.es.amazonaws.com:443], URI [/products], status line [HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable]
{"error":"Content-Type header [application/vnd.elasticsearch+json; compatible-with=8] is not supported","status":406}
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.elc.ElasticsearchExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ElasticsearchExceptionTranslator.java:111) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.elc.ElasticsearchExceptionTranslator.translateException(ElasticsearchExceptionTranslator.java:65) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.elc.ChildTemplate.execute(ChildTemplate.java:73) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.elc.IndicesTemplate.doCreate(IndicesTemplate.java:145) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.elc.IndicesTemplate.createWithMapping(IndicesTemplate.java:135) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleElasticsearchRepository.createIndexAndMappingIfNeeded(SimpleElasticsearchRepository.java:94) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleElasticsearchRepository.<init>(SimpleElasticsearchRepository.java:87) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:502) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:486) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:208) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar:6.1.11]
    ... 71 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: method [PUT], host [https://search-atosell-ezrvtmvhttw6fjztfsgkbndgbu.eu-central-1.es.amazonaws.com:443], URI [/products], status line [HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable]
{"error":"Content-Type header [application/vnd.elasticsearch+json; compatible-with=8] is not supported","status":406}
    at


Process finished with exit code 1


is there reason to use spring-data-elasticsearch instead of spring-data-opensearch?
